How to highlight a specific date in JCalendar (already tried implementing previous answers)
So I have a problem with highlighting specific dates on my JCalendar using the IDateEvaluator. I want it to be so that based on the dates that the user inserted into the database, the IDateEvaluator highlights it on the JCalendar. I tried to fix it based on all the answers from the previous posts here about this issue, but I was either never able to get the right date to be highlighted or the highlight just never worked.
This is what I have so far:
public class JCalendar4 {

    SQLConnection con = new SQLConnection(); // connection to database
    
    private static class Evaluator implements IDateEvaluator {
    
        private List<Date> assignmentDates = new ArrayList<>();
    
        public void add(Date dates) {
            assignmentDates.add(dates);
        }
        
        public void remove(Date date) {
            assignmentDates.remove(date);
        }
    
        public void setDates(List<Date> dates) {
            assignmentDates.addAll(dates);
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isSpecial(Date date) {
            return assignmentDates.contains(date);
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public Color getSpecialForegroundColor() {
            return Color.MAGENTA;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String getSpecialTooltip() {
            return "Highlighted Event";
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isInvalid(Date date) {
            return false;
        }
    
        @Override
        public Color getInvalidForegroundColor() {
            return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public Color getInvalidBackroundColor() {
            return null;    
        }
    
        @Override
        public String getInvalidTooltip() {
            return null;    
        }
    
        @Override
        public Color getSpecialBackroundColor() {
            return Color.MAGENTA; //System.out.println(color);
        }
        
    
    }
    
    private void display() {
        
        List<Date> datesList = new ArrayList<>();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        
        // example of the date I stored in my database
        try {
            datesList.add(dateFormat.parse("2019-09-26"));
            datesList.add(dateFormat.parse("2020-05-24"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }
        
        JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser(); 
        List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Calendar");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JCalendar jc = new JCalendar();
    
        
        for(int i = 0; i < datesList.size(); i++) {
            dates.add(createDate(datesList.get(i)));
        }
    
        Evaluator evaluator = new Evaluator();
        evaluator.setDates(dates);
        
        jc.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(evaluator);
        jc.setCalendar(jc.getCalendar());
        
        f.add(jc);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        jc.repaint();
    
    }
    
    private Date createDate(Date d) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(d);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return (c.getTime());
    }
       
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new JCalendar4()::display);
        
    
     }   

}

It's weird because the getSpecialForegroundColor() method works as intended and the days in the JCalendar are displayed in the Magenta color. But for some reason, they're not getting highlighted. I thought that maybe the overriding wasn't correct so I used a print statement in the getSpecialBackroundColor(), and it does print the terminal so now I'm just even more confused. Can somebody help me fix my code so the getSpecialBackroundColor() function works? So far, it just appears like this:
2 3

Did you see this question?

yeah I saw that question and i tried it as well :( It always highlights the wrong date for some reason so I figured the IDateEvaluator might be more precise

@luna It works as it should be, see https://i.ibb.co/25tFDg0/Screenshot-20241231-094623.png (on openjdk version "17.0.13", linux). Your screenshot doesn't match the source code, specially as the highlighted dates (at least with the foreground) are not the dates from the given MCVE. Please show the screenshot you get with the MCVE you have added to the question.

Okay! I added the photos. For some reason, it's still not highlighting for me

@luna Please check which "look and feel" you are using for your java application on macos. Also try setting the foreground and background color of an ordinary JButton and see if you can change the look of such a button.

The look and feel I'm using is this: com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel. I also tried to set the foreground color of an ordinary JButton and it works, but the background color is just white regardless of the colors I change it to.

@Progman It turns out my look and feel might not support some of the color changes. Thanks for the response! I changed the look and feel and it works now

@luna perhaps you could post an answer?
